# How to order by optional association with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Scenario:

- Pupils have many grade progressions.
- A grade progression belongs to a polymorphic progressable (either a subject or topic), and a score (decimal).
- Pupils may not yet have a grade progression recorded for
  all progressables.

I need:

- A list of Pupils ordered by grade score (highest first) for any given progressable.
- Pupils without grades for the progressable should appear last.
- If a Pupil has multiple grades for the progressable then the most recent should be used.

I've tried

```
Pupil.left_joins(:grade_progressions).where(grade_progressions: { progressable: progressable })
                                     .order('grade_progressions.score DESC')
```

however, this does not work because it excludes any pupils without a grade for the progressable.

With raw SQL this should be possible by specifying the condition on the `LEFT JOIN` however I can't find a way to do this with ActiveRecord object syntax. I'd like to avoid specifying the join as a string if possible.

How can I author an ActiveRecord query to order by an optional polymorphic association in this way?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this @tommarshall?

Answer (score 0):

Rails 5 has a native `.left_outer_joins` method. Previously you needed to specify the join as a string or use `.includes` which often has unintended results.

An `OUTER JOIN` unlike the SQL default `INNER JOIN` includes rows that have no matches in the joined table.

Comment: I've tried `.left_outer_joins` however that's still only returns pupils where grade progressions exist. I believe that's due to the `.where` rather than the join however. I believe moving that condition up into the join should resolve that, but I can't workout how to do that with ActiveRecord's object syntax.